# LyX 2.0.7.1, Mac 10.7.5: LyX text scrolls while I'm working on it

Tags: lyx

LyX 2.0.7.1, Mac 10.7.5: LyX text scrolls while I'm working on it. I often need to hit UNDO to find my way back to the insertion point.

26 Feb 2015: I have the same (continuing) problem with Mac 10.7.5 and Lyx 2.1.3.

Comment: This sounds like a LyX bug. Consider waiting a couple of days for LyX 2.1 to come out and if that does not fix things post a bug report at http://www.lyx.org/trac

Comment: You could try the Mac installation file for LyX 2.1 here. It is by the main LyX developer for Macs and will (in a couple of days) likely be the final installation file that will be released. https://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-devel@lists.lyx.org/msg183740.html

Comment: Are there any news here?